# Comparison between structs in C using bitfields

Tags: c, memory, struct, bit-fields

So I really can't understand the difference between these two code segments. What I know about bit field is that I reserve in memory how many BITS I will use for this int. But why negative number appear in 2nd Struct?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct {
        unsigned int i:1;
        unsigned int k:31;
        int x;
}Struc1;
typedef struct{
        int i:1;
        int k:4;
        int x;
}Struc2;
int main()
{
        Struc1 s1={1,13,13};
        printf("%d %d %d\n",s1.i,s1.k,s1.x);
        Struc2 s2={1,13,13};
        printf("%d %d %d\n",s2.i,s2.k,s2.x);
        return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1 13 13
-1 -3 13
```

Comment: Do you know how negatives represented in C? Hint: The leftmost bit is the sign.

Comment: Almost everything about bit-fields is implementation defined.  When you store `13` into a 4-bit bit field, you may get a signed or an unsigned value stored.  `13` has the bit pattern `1101`; the high bit is set; it will be treated as negative if your plain `int` bit-fields are signed types.  If you want it unsigned, say so: `unsigned k:4;` (the `int` is optional in this context).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am wondering if it is really possible to get positive `13` in the 4 bit field? How?

Comment: so when an int is allocated using a bitfield it can contain negative number but why?

Comment: [C11 §6.7.2.1 footnote 125](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note125) As specified in 6.7.2 above, if the actual type specifier used is `int` or a typedef-name defined as `int`, then it is implementation-defined whether the bit-field is signed or unsigned.  And [C11 §6.7.2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2p5) ¶5 Each of the comma-separated multisets designates the same type, except that for bit-fields, it is implementation-defined whether the specifier `int` designates the same type as `signed int` or the same type as `unsigned int`.

Comment: Those notes means that you can't tell what value is stored in an `int x:1;` bit-field.  It can store zero or non-zero; you can't tell whether the non-zero is `-1` or `+1` except by reading the compiler documentation — or experimentation.  It has no portable interpretation, but that's hardly a major problem since bit-fields generally have no portable interpretation.

Comment: @ZeyadIbrahim: Normally, `int` means the same as `signed int`; bit-fields are the only place I can think of where it sometimes means the same as `unsigned int` — and that depends on your compiler.  So, by default, most people would expect an `int` member of a structure to be a signed quantity.

Answer (score 3):

This is a place in C where `int`, `signed int` may differ.

**With bit-fields**, An `int` without a `signed` or `unsigned` may be treated as `signed int` or `unsigned int`.  Based on OP's reported output, this implementation defined behavior of  `int` appears to be like `signed int`.

```
typedef struct{
  int i:1;  // like signed int i:1; for OP
  int k:4;  // like signed int k:4; for OP
  int x;
}Struc2;
```

The `i` bit-field likely has the range `[-1...0]` and `k` has `[-8...7]`. Initializing a *signed integer* via `Struc2 s2={1,13,13};` with a value outside its range is *implementation defined* (Details: C11dr 6.3.1.3 3).

A common *implementation defined* behavior is to wrap around.  So like `Struc2 s2 = {1-2, 13-16, 13};` or `Struc2 s2 = {-1, -3, 13};`

---

When using bit-fields, recommend to use `unsigned` whenever possible.  If `int` bit-fields are needed, use `signed int`.

Answer (score 1):

**Structure bit filed** means reserving memory in terms of **bits** for data member of structure. While working on `bit-field` you should take care of `sign bit` if input is of `signed` type.

**memory allocation for struc2** :

```
typedef struct{
        int i:1;
        int k:4;
        int x;
}Struc2;
```

**1)** For member `i` only `one bits` is reserved as

```
 -------
|  1    |
 -------
        i
        |
        this is only first and last bit
```

`int i : 1 ;` If there is no type mentioned for **variable/constant** then by default compiler will consider as **signed** type and if **sign(MSB)** bit of signed integer is `1` means it will be **negative** no. `2's complement` of `1` is `-1`. so `s2.i = -1`

**Note :** In C, Negative no are stored in memory in form of **two's complement**

**2)** for member `k`, `4 bits` are reserved (in that you are storing `13`), it looks like below

```
       ---------------------------
13 => | 1   |    1   |  0   |  1  |
       ---------------------------
       0x103  0x102   0x101  0x100                      
        |
      sign bit
```

In this case also `sign bit` is `1` so `s2.k` will be **negative** and how much ? take **two's complement**(one's complement + 1).

```
        13 => 1101
           => 0010 (one's complement)
                +1
              -----
              0011 => 3  since sign bit was 1 so s2.k = -3
              -----
```

Answer (score 0):

Your system is little endian so first bit is signed bit from right most bit that's why in your second `struct` you are inserting odd numbers so it takes first bit as signed bit and give a negative value.

```
 typedef struct{   
    int i:1;   //Here you inserting **1** so it will take as signed bit. 
    int k:4;   //Here you inserting odd value **13** so it will take negative
    int x;     //This is also signed but it is **32** bit so it has enough space to store your **13** integer value.
  }Struc2;
```

if you don't want negative value then give it as a `unsigned` or increase the bits allocation.Cheers..